# How to show Stimulsoft Report in C# windows form project?

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

Im using [Stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/net) for reporting in my c# windows project.

Its my code in C# win form project:

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();

report.Load(@"D:\MyReport.mrt");
report.Show();
```

the result is like this:

[image]

I want to know how can I show this report in Windows form without designer like above pic. The report should be displayed in my form. So, is there any control that i can add in my form and then I show my report in that viewer control? Same as CrystalReportViewer control?
I want to show that in my forms, not in anothers.

Thanks for any helping...

Comment: Which version do you use? There is no ShowDialog() method of the StiReport class.

Comment: @HighAley You are right, it dosent have ShowDialog() method, I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use StiViewerControl.

Comment: I add these dll in my project : stimulsoft.Base, stimulsoft.Design, stimulsoft.Report, stimulsoft.Report.Win. but now I have just Report control in my toolbox, I dont have StiViewerContro.

Comment: I did not use Stimulsoft. But just in case. Maybe now this is related to a question like "How to add a control to the toolbox?". You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931328/how-do-i-add-my-new-user-control-to-the-toolbox-or-a-new-winform .

Comment: This has been flagged as a low quality post. It would help if you could supply an explanation why the OP should use StiViewerControl.

Comment: The StiViewerControl is located in the Stimulsoft.Report.Win assembly. If you don't have this control in the Toolbox you could add it manually.
How to add controls you could learn in the Visual Studion documentation.

Comment: @DeanOC,  Elahe asked the control that he could use on his form. I had answed this question. What additional expanation do you need? He could find all explanation with sample in the Stimulsoft Documantation if he had bought the product legally, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: I did not flag your answer. I just added the comment. SO prefers answers with a bit of explanation why your suggestion addresses the problem.